# bash utility 'dialog' leaves a messy screen

Tags: bash, scripts, dialog

When I run this script it displays options in a menu style on my terminal and then runs the relavent command in the script.

[image: Script Screen]

```
#!/bin/sh
TEMP=/tmp/answer$$
dialog --ascii-lines --title "Administrative tasks"  --menu  "Tasks :" 20 0 0 1 "Display firewall settings" 2 "Restore firewall settings" 3 "Flush Firewall settings" 2>$TEMP
choice=`cat $TEMP`
case $choice in
        1)      iptables -L
                ;;
        2)      iptables-restore </etc/iptables.firewall.rules
                iptables -L
                ;;
        3)      iptables --flush
                iptables -L
                ;;
esac
echo Selected $choice
```

But when it exits the screen is messed up.

Is there a way to "save" the state of screen before I ran this and restore it?

Is there a better "Windows" scripting program that runs in a text screen?

[image: Messed up Screen]

Comment: How about using `screen`

Comment: @ElefantPhace I ran this is a "screen' session and thought that was the issue, nah, it still messes the screen. Unless you mean piping the command into screen? Can that be done? (PS: When `screen` exits, it too clears the screen)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of keeping your main terminal in a screen then starting a new one for the dialog then returning to your main one after done with dialog. Can't test this ATM though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`dialog` manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/dialog.1.html) mentions [`whiptail`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/whiptail.1.html) (in a rather deprecating fashion). It does not have the `--ascii-lines` option, but it does not mess up the screen either:

[image: terminal screenshot with aftermaths of dialog and whiptail]

The script:

```
#!/bin/sh
TEMP=/tmp/answer$$
whiptail --title "Administrative tasks"  --menu  "Tasks :" 20 0 0 1 "Display firewall settings" 2 "Restore firewall settings" 3 "Flush Firewall settings" 2>$TEMP
choice=`cat $TEMP`
case $choice in
        1)      echo 1 #iptables -L
                ;;
        2)      echo 2 #iptables-restore </etc/iptables.firewall.rules
                #iptables -L
                ;;
        3)      echo 3 #iptables --flush
                #iptables -L
                ;;
esac
echo Selected $choice
```

The display from `whiptail`:
[image: screenshot of whiptail in action]

Among other things, `whiptail` is based on [`newt`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newt_(programming_library)) instead of `ncurses`. It is also a dependency of `ubuntu-minimal`, so it should be installed on all Ubuntu systems by default (at least, as of 14.04).

Comment: Very nice, fits the bill nicely, will do some more testing but looks like this is the solution I need. Thanks.

Comment: Perfect seems it doesn't need the --ascii-lines parameter as it works. Was easy to update script, straight replace of commands.

Answer (score 16):

I know it's late, but maybe you want to switch to the *alternate screen* (like `nano`, `vim`, and others do), so you could give a try to the `--keep-tite` option.

From the *dialog*'s man page:

> **--keep-tite**: Normally dialog checks to see if it is running in an xterm, and in that case tries to suppress the initialization strings that would make it switch to the alternate screen. Switching between the normal and alternate screens is visually distracting in a script which runs dialog several times. Use this option to allow dialog to use those initialization strings.

Here's an example:

```
echo "Write something before invoking dialog."
dialog --keep-tite --msgbox "Hello world!" 0 0
```

After the user hits OK, the output printed before invoking `dialog ...` is restored.

Comment: nope, problem persists (dialog 1.2 in gnome terminal 3.14)

Comment: This worked for me using dialog 1.2, bash 4.3 and several terminal emulators. Thank you.

Comment: This was it! By using the `--keep-tite` switch, the previous screen comes back upon exiting the `dialog` command. This is definitely the cleanest option, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `clear` after the `dialog` line:

```
...
dialog --ascii-lines --title "Administrative tasks"  --menu  "Tasks :" 20 0 0 1 "Display firewall settings" 2 "Restore firewall settings" 3 "Flush Firewall settings" 2>$TEMP
clear #clears the terminal screen
choice=`cat $TEMP`
case $choice in
...
```

Comment: That clears the screen, all previous text is lost. Hence the need to "restore" the screen state. I had the clear in there myself but I would like to restore the screen state. That way I can still see the text that was on the screen before I executed the command.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible with the screen command.

run this using screen as below,

```
screen bash yourcommand.sh
```

This would show the dialog screen then collect the choice.
Also this would restore the existing screen on exit.